# java assigning values to an array

Tags: java, arrays

so i'm creating a program in java where you enter scores and it classifies them into deciles (0-9, 10-19, 20-29, ... 80-89, 90-100) and I've got a grasp on how the program is supposed to work but I'm missing one key element. I create an array with 10 elements (one for each decile range). Once the user inputs their score it divides by 10 and then needs to put the score into it's appropriate spot in the array, but that's where I'm lost. It has to do a bunch of things after that, that I understand but how am I supposed to tell the code when someone enters 55 to increase the 50-59 part of the array by 1 and so on?

Comment: Study up on integer division.   Divide 59 by 10 and you get 5.

Answer (score 2):

Um, it sounds like you just want:

```
bucketedScores[score / 10]++;
```

Don't you? Or possibly clearer:

```
bucketedScores[score / 10] = roughScores[score / 10] + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int index = value / 10;
myArray[index] += 1;
```

FYI, given what you said, you will get an IndexOutOfBoundsException with a score of 100. May need to deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

As the range is has 101 values from 0 to 101 you need to do more than divide by 10.

Do you mean like?

```
int[] scores = new int[10];

int decile = ...
int score = ....

scores[Math.min(9, decile/10)] += score;
```

This ensures that 100 is mapped to 9. Another solutions is to use `(int)(decile/10.1)` which would maps 0 to 10 to the first decile.

Comment: If there are deciles 0..10, why do you divide decile by 10??

Comment: as each decile has 10 in them, thus the name. The problem is there is 11 deciles between 0 and 100.

Comment: But dividing decile by ten you'll only ever get zero or one.  The OP's question was about how to calculate decile.

Comment: When you divide by 10 you get the 0th, 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc decile. My point is that there is 11 deciles not 10.

Comment: I would say I am dividing by 10 to get the number of the decile (range of 10)

Comment: Ie, you *should* be dividing "centile" or "percentile", and assigning the result to "decile".

Comment: a centile is a group of 100 so you need to multiple your centile to get a decile. a percentile is per-100 or the inverse of the centile number.

Comment: Check your dictionary -- centile and percentile are the same thing.

Comment: @HotLicks Sorry for the confusion. I knew something was not going to work but was confused as to what. Changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way....

`bucketedScores[score / 10] = roughScores[score / 10] + 1;`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like

```
int[] myarray = new int[10];
 // Divide and increase the number returned (like 84/10 = 8 in integer division)
myarray[num/10]++
```

Though 100 would throw it off, you would need a special case for that one.

Comment: Well, I was going to downvote you for initializing the array when that's unnecessary.  But I won't because you did raise the point that 100 is a special case.

Comment: FYI, don't need to init array with `0`, that is the default value for `int`

Comment: i just figured i would do an if case and say if score = 100 to put it into the 90-100 decile, but how would i phrase that?

Comment: Might be simpler to just use `if (num == 100) num = 99` then you dont have to worry about the rest of the code executing as normal

Answer (score 0):

According to the Question
get into loops say for example i hope you're dividing 100 values 10-10 each. Use  for loops and check and categorize it by assigning the input to a temporary variable for each iteration of inputs.

```
for(int i=0; i<=100; i++)
{
    if(a[i] >= 0 && a[i] < 10)
                your desired o/p(execution)
     else if(a[i] > 10 && a[i] < 20)
                your desired o/p(execution)
}
```